# Simple Calculation gives wrong result

Tags: c++, math

I have this simple piece of code:

```
Logger::LogFloat("width", m_BMPLoader->GetWidth());
Logger::LogFloat("height", m_BMPLoader->GetHeight());
Logger::LogFloat("width / 4", (m_BMPLoader->GetWidth() / 4));
Logger::LogFloat("height / 4", (m_BMPLoader->GetHeight() /4));
Logger::LogFloat("-width / 4", -(m_BMPLoader->GetWidth() / 4));
Logger::LogFloat("-height / 4", -(m_BMPLoader->GetHeight() / 4));
Logger::LogFloat("-width /4 * Plane", -(m_BMPLoader->GetWidth() / 4) * PLANE_WIDTH);
Logger::LogFloat("-height / 4 * Plane", -(m_BMPLoader->GetHeight() / 4) * PLANE_WIDTH);
```

Giving this result:

```
width: 128
height: 128
width / 4: 32
height / 4: 32
-width / 4: 4.29497e+009          //should be -32
-height / 4: 4.29497e+009         //should be -32
-width /4 * Plane: 4.29497e+009   //should be -160
-height / 4 * Plane: 4.29497e+009 //should be -160
```

EDIT: Solved. I used unsigned int and signed it.

Comment: You should probably accept one of the answers then.  (Specifically the one you think is most helpful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is an `unsigned int`, then `-x` is also an `unsigned int`, with the value pow(2,n)-x, where `n` is the number of bits in an `unsigned int`.

You will need a cast somewhere to a signed type (integral or floating type).

Answer (score 1):

unsigned arithmetic operates modulo 2^n for some value n.  `-(m_BMPLoader->GetWidth() / 4)` is actually being calculated as 2^32 - 32, which is approximately 4294967264 - hence your results.